# laravel elequent query with addSelect

Tags: laravel

I have query

```
$result = Item::
        addSelect([
        'issuedQty' => IssuedItem::select( DB::Raw('SUM(qty)'))
            ->groupBy('item_id')
            ->whereColumn('item_id', 'items.id')
            ])
        ->addSelect([
            'receivedQty' => Order::select( DB::Raw('SUM(qty)'))
                ->groupBy('item_id')
                ->whereColumn('item_id', 'items.id')
                ])
        ->get();
```

the out put of this query

```
id: 1,
name: "polo-mi",
category_id: 1,
initialQty: 5,
created_at: null,
updated_at: null,
issuedQty: "34",
receivedQty: "6"
```

I want the the balance Qty  from issuedQty - receivedQty

how I can get this done...

Answer (score 1):

why not map that collection:

```
$result->map(function ($item){
    $item->balance =$item->issuedQty - $item->receivedQty;
    return $item;
});
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'issuedQty' in 'field list' (SQL: select `items`.*, issuedQty - receivedQty as balance from `items`)

Comment: try mapping the collection

Comment: Yes, it is giving the balance, but incase if I want use orderByDesc( ) , is it possible ?

Comment: You can try `sortBy()`  or `sortByDesc()` collection methods https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby

Comment: @OMR You need to return $item from within the closure of map and assign the result of map function back to $result variable

Comment: @Donkarnash thanks, it work with or without return, I tested it, but I will added it for clarity

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map map returns a new collection and after manipulating each item of collection within the closure, item has to be returned back from the closure. Whatever is returned from within the closure will replace the original item

Comment: I got it ...

if ( isset( $orderByBalance)) {
      $sorderByBalance = $query->sortByDesc('balance');
      return $sorderByBalance->values()->all();

    } else {
       // $result = $query->max('balance');
       $result = $query;
        return $result;
    }

Comment: good, you can mark my answer as 'accepted' so we consider this question as 'solved'

Comment: Thanks for your support but still i have issue with pagination ... 
        
`$sorderByBalance = $query->sortByDesc('balance');
      return $sorderByBalance->values()->all();`

when I use sortBy( ) method in collection, it does not return the pagination link ....

Comment: using collection method, I am not getting the pagination link back , is there any way to get this balance property in query builder / eloquent query ?